# How to insert data from a query into another table using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have prepared a sql query and want to run this on my mssql 2008 database, the result of the query to be inserted into another table. The reason for doing this is my original query is very time consuming when it is run directly in my application.

So, I am trying to create a ready table with all the data and then just use this table in my app; thus reducing the query time. I am trying to use SSIS to execute a sql task, but don't know how to insert the data into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an SSIS package could you do an INSERT INTO using a SQL procedure?

If you require an SSIS package you could create the procedure and then run the following in an Execute SQL task.

```
EXEC DatabaseName.schema.MyProcedure
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. but I need to run this query every night to update this report table,so the next day it has the latest data for the clients.

Comment: You could create a SQL Server Agent job that runs the stored procedure every night. The procedure would then update the table every night with the latest data.